# IOS Core Telephony warning and app store query

Tags: ios, core-telephony

I was making a simple app where I wanted to allow user to make specific phone calls from the app.

We have a lot of special numbers over here which include * and # to get some specific data. I began writing the app and used this initially to make the call

```
NSString * phonenumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",
@"tel://*188*",
number.text,
@"#"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phonenumber]];
```

While this method works on normal digits, the special characters are ignored so i ventured looking for the solution and found that the CoreTelephony Framework offers this capability.

My new method includes

- adding the core telephony binary to the project
- referencing the headers
- using CTCallDialWithID(@"*000*0000#",-1); to make the call

Now everything works perfectly fine and here are my concerns

- I get a warning which says "implicit declaration of function CTCallDialwithID is invalid  in c99". I do not know if i should just ignore this or if I have missed something ?
- I have been doing some research on core telephony, some people say app store will not accept an app with this, is this true ? The answers seem 2 years ago so I don;t know if things have changed, I mean apple is including the binary themselves and it is not a private framework like before right ? So will the app get accepted on the app store if I use this method?

Thank You

Comment: Can you please provide the sample code that you have used to dial ussd numbers successfully? Which headers do you include Since the definition for CTCallDiallWithID is not in coretelephony headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Core Telephony` framework is a valid framework. But there is no public method or function named `CTCallDialWithID`. That must be a private API. Apple will definitely reject your app for using a private API. You can only use the Core Telephony APIs documented by Apple. Any other use will cause a rejection (like in this case).

Comment: Ok this does make me a bit sad as I was able to achieve what I needed. Is there any way to make calls using special characters then or no chance for this ?

Comment: The answer you gave is very accurate and correct. Thank You for your time.